# Automate jar export across projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jar, export

I have a Google Web Toolkit project for which i include a second project into the build path. This other project has a lot of my commonly used functions and classes. Building the project works fine but to avoid run time errors i have to jar the second project into the WAR folder of the GAE project.
The process of jar/exporting the second project into the first is a manual process that i do with a right click in eclipse.

Is there a way to automate the process of jar/exporting to WAR of the second project into a location on the first?

Would i do this with an ANT script?
Or is there a way this can be done within Eclipse itself.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in for some reading mate :)

Step 1 : Create a JAR of the first project ( Read **[this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-jar-file-using-ant.html)**). In the `jar` task you could put as the path of your GAE's folder lib as the `destfile` like so :

```
<target name="jar">
        <jar basedir="bin" destfile="../GAE_PROJECT/war/WEB-INF/lib/${project-name}.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${builder}" />
                <attribute name="Built-On" value="${build-info.current-date}" />
                <attribute name="Built-At" value="${build-info.current-time}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

Step 2 : Create the WAR for your GAE project ( Read the official documentation **[here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant)** ). The documentation shows how the jars in the lib are included :

```
 <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
 </fileset>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. The eclipse auto build now runs the jar(build-jar) target whenever there is changed to my library project. This is going to save me a lot of time.